# Autogenerate UUID in Liquibase - Mysql MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb, uuid, liquibase

I was trying to create a table whose primary key should be an autogenerated UUID on isertion.

```
mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.22-MariaDB, for osx10.11 (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

This is the changeset I have tried :

```
   <changeSet author="shalinlk" id="201705161522">
    <createTable tableName="quiz_question">
        <column valueComputed="UUID()" name="id" type="CHAR(36)">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="quiz_id" type="CHAR(36)">
            <constraints nullable="true" foreignKeyName="fk_quiz_question_quiz_id"
                         references="quiz(id)"/>
        </column>
        <column name="question_id" type="CHAR(36)">
            <constraints nullable="true" foreignKeyName="fk_quiz_question_question_id"
                         references="question(id)"/>
        </column>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>
```

But this is not even treating the **valueComputed** property in the corresponding query generated. Can anyone help please.

Note : the query

```
select UUID();
```

is working correctly when I tried in mysql terminal.

**Edit** :
The query generated is

```
CREATE TABLE quiz_question (
    id CHAR(36), 
    quiz_id CHAR(36) NULL, 
    question_id CHAR(36) NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT PK_QUIZ_QUESTION PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    CONSTRAINT fk_quiz_question_question_id FOREIGN KEY (question_id) 
    REFERENCES question(id), 
    CONSTRAINT fk_quiz_question_quiz_id FOREIGN KEY (quiz_id) REFERENCES quiz(id))
```

I have removed fields that are not relevant.

**Edit** : 
Will be helpful if anyone can point out some reference/example on this.

Comment: What does the generated query look like?

Comment: CREATE TABLE quiz_question (id CHAR(36), quiz_id CHAR(36) NULL, question_id CHAR(36) NULL,  CONSTRAINT PK_QUIZ_QUESTION PRIMARY KEY (id), CONSTRAINT fk_quiz_question_question_id FOREIGN KEY (question_id) REFERENCES question(id), CONSTRAINT fk_quiz_question_quiz_id FOREIGN KEY (quiz_id) REFERENCES quiz(id))]

Comment: Please do not put code in comments. Edit your answer to add the info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, `valueComputed` is used in expressions for example in insert or update. It's hard to know for sure, because the LiquiBase documentation is pretty vague on this attribute.

You seem to be using it as if it's the default for a column in a new table definition. I assume the attribute would be `defaultValueComputed` for this.

But MySQL doesn't support expressions for column defaults. You can't make a table like this in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE quiz_question (
    id CHAR(36) DEFAULT UUID(), 
    ...
```

You would have to create a trigger to assign UUID() to the primary key column. Something like the following:

```
CREATE TRIGGER quiz_question_ins BEFORE INSERT ON quiz_question
FOR EACH ROW SET id = COALESCE(id, UUID());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're about to store UUIDs in mysql/mariadb, *please don't use varchar/char fields*. They are just a 128-bit binary values, outputted with a nice block separation and hex formatted.

Using CHAR(36), which is probably using an utf8-encoded charset and uses at least 3 Bytes per character, you'd need 36*3 = 108 Bytes to store each UUID.

Instead, you can *use a BINARY(16) field* to store the underlying value (=16 Bytes...). Sadly, mysql doesn't do that out of the box. See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid for a deeper explanation and more information how to convert uuids in mysql.